# Placement of OnActivityResult with OnClicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have implemented a 3rd party camera scanning app within a project of mine

I have an adaptor that extends a viewholder so i can have a custom layout

Within a view i have a button

When i create the view i add an OnclickListener to the image which i want to make clickable

i want this OnclickListener to call the camera but i need to call an startActivityForResult

i am confused about the placement of the onActivityResult when calling in this way.

my current attempts have been to create a seperate class(scan_activity) which extends activity but i couldnt get the onclicklistener to start the class

i have then attempted to declare it within the setOnClickListener, which as you can guess also failed.

Im guessing the call to the class is the way forward.im sure its an easy fix, but im not seeing it

please help

thanks in advance

```
    imgCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, 1);

            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,99);
        }
                                 }
   );
```

and the class

```
imgCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              new ScanActivity
            }
                                     }
       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option should work. You create an `Intent` object and you specify activity component as a parameter. Android will create an `Activity` object for you, so, never do that manually. Android should manage the lifecycle of activity.

By starting activity for result you tell Android that it should call `onActivityResult` callback with request code 99 on your first activity when `ScanActivity` will be closed.

Handling `onActivityResult` in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 99) {
        // handle your result here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example construct.  I'm afraid I can't follow your thinking . Not a criticism by the way ha

Comment: What code do you want me to provide? To start the ScanActivity your first code with Intent should work fine. If it doesn't start the activity then either your click event is not fired or there is an issue inside ScanActivity itself. If it does start and you need to handle the result, I can provide the code on how to handle that.

Comment: Im startibg to understand a little. I tried breakpoints on the oncreate within scan activity but nothing fired . I'll retest now. Any examples would be welcome